# Page refreshing on Submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax-search.php

they provided me what I'm looking for. But the only problem I'm facing is, when I press enter button, the page is refreshing :( but I don't want to do that.

DEMO:

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax-search-demo.htm

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        #displayDiv
        {
            background-color: #ffeeaa;
            width: 200;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxFunction(str) {
            var httpxml;
            try {
                // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e) {
                // Internet Explorer
                try {
                    httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    try {
                        httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function stateChanged() {
                if (httpxml.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = httpxml.responseText;

                }
            }
            var url = "ajax-search-demock.php";
            url = url + "?txt=" + str;
            url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            httpxml.open("GET", url, true);
            httpxml.send(null);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);" name="username" />
        <div id="displayDiv">
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE (ajax-search-demock.php)**

```
<?
//***************************************
// This is downloaded from www.plus2net.com //
/// You can distribute this code with the link to www.plus2net.com ///
// Please don't remove the link to www.plus2net.com ///
// This is for your learning only not for commercial use. ///////
//The author is not responsible for any type of loss or problem or damage on using this script.//
/// You can use it at your own risk. /////
//*****************************************
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR);
////// Your Database Details here /////////
$dbservertype='mysql';
$servername='127.0.0.1';
$dbusername='test';
$dbpassword='test';
$dbname='sql_tutorial';

////////////////////////////////////////
////// DONOT EDIT BELOW /////////
///////////////////////////////////////

connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
  global $link;
  $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
  if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
  mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}
///////////////////// Main Code sarts ////////


$in=$_GET['txt'];
$msg="";
if(strlen($in)>0 and strlen($in) <20 ){
  $t=mysql_query("select name, id from student where name like '$in%'");
  while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($t)){
    $msg.=$nt[name]."->$nt[id]<br>";
  }
}
echo $msg;

?>
```

**UPDATE :**

ok the ENTER thing is SOLVED :D it is really great!!.. have one more request please

i want to get the data only when the input reaches 8 characters. is it possible ?

Comment: `onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);"` just add **return false** like this `onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);return false`

Comment: In a real-world situation, make it work without JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually submitting anything, so technically you don't need the `<form>` element at all, just remove it and leave the rest as is.

Alternatively, if you're a stickler for strict standards, set `action="javascript:void(null)` on the form to prevent it doing anything.

Comment: There is no submit button in here, so does form tag's existence matter ?

Comment: It is default behaviour for a form containing a single input to submit when the Enter key is pressed, even without a submit button. If more than one form element is present, the standard behaviour is to simulate a click on the first submit button in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a submit button to the form (and hide in in your CSS) and put the following into it;

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return false;"/>
```

Comment: but when i'm trying to select this as answer. TICK mark is not coming :( am trying...

Comment: I think it will only let you after so many minutes, glad it worked for you!

Comment: i have one more request please

i want to get the data only when the input reaches 8 characters. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes and it will work:

> return false;

after this line :

> httpxml.send(null);

AND

> onkeyup="return ajaxFunction(this.value);"

inslead of :

> onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);"

or you can also add following in to form tag:

> onsubmit="return false;"

Agree with @Kolink "If you don't want to submit date then there is no need for form tag